# Dantzig's algorithm for longest path

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

What I am looking for is a algorithm from Dantzig which should find a longest way in digraph. Couple of science sources mention this algorithm so afterwhile I have been able to track it down to this book:

https://books.google.cz/books?id=YfdgAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=Gondran,+Michel+and+Minoux,+Michel.+Graphes+et+algorithmes.+dantzig&source=bl&ots=T4cjgcB38K&sig=ACfU3U0HSGy4bjfpXckDf9DjBIihagX02g&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLus709fztAhXN8qQKHUceB4IQ6AEwEXoECBYQAg#v=onepage&q=du%20plus%20long&f=false

since I don't speak french it is matter of time until I translate all of that. I am unable to find any english-written resources. If you have knowledge of this algorithm, I would be much obliged if you pointed me to alternative resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I found it. The simple trick is to:

1. multiply all arcs by -1
2. find the shortest path in graph using Dantzig's algorithm (desribed in the book as Algorithm 10)
3. multiply result by -1

Good thing is this algorithm should also work for multigraphs.

UPDATE: I ended up using Bellman-Ford algorithm with the modification described above. Worked for directed multigraph with negative edges.

Comment: Note that this only works for acyclic graphs, because otherwise step 1 creates negative length cycles.